# Hibernate: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my current spring project, when I try store in the database a record based on this entty:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="produto")
public class Produto {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="nome", nullable=false, unique=true)
    @Order(value=1)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name="preco", nullable=false)
    @Order(value=2)
    private Float preco;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="categoria")
    @Cascade(value = { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL })
    @Order(value=3)
    private Categoria categoria;

    @Column(name="resumo", length=140)
    @Order(value=4)
    private String resumo;

    @Column(name="descricao", length=65535)
    @Order(value=5)
    private String descricao;
}
```

I am getting this error: http://www.klebermota.eti.br/wp-content/erro.html

The error is only displayed when I select an item in the select from the form below. If I don't select an option, the record is stored without problem.

```
<form id="command" class="form" action="/loja/Produto/cadastra" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3><label for="nome" class="label label-default">nome</label></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3><label for="preco" class="label label-default">preco</label></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="preco" name="preco" pattern="[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{2}" class="form-control valida" type="text" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3><label for="categoria" class="label label-default">categoria</label></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">

                <select id="categoria.id" name="categoria.id" class="form-control select categoria" data-nome="Categoria" data-lista="/loja/Produto/listagem3.json"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3><label for="resumo" class="label label-default">resumo</label></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="resumo" name="resumo" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3><label for="descricao" class="label label-default">descricao</label></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <textarea id="descricao" name="descricao" class="form-control" rows="25" cols="50"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">&iacute;cone do produto (jpeg, 171x180)</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <input type="file" name="icone" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">imagem da capa (jpeg, 1280x250)</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">capturas de tela (jpeg, 960x720)</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">cadastrar</button> </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Anyone can tell me what's wrong here? I am a bit stucked with this for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the working solution for this problem was this configuration for the class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="produto")
public class Produto {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="nome", length=32, nullable=false, unique=true)
    @Order(value=1)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name="titulo", length=32, nullable=false)
    @Order(value=2)
    private String titulo;

    @Column(name="preco")
    @Order(value=3)
    private Float preco;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categoria")
    @Order(value=4)
    private Categoria categoria;

    @Column(name="descricao", length=65535)
    @Order(value=5)
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name="destaque")
    @Order(value=6)
    private boolean destaque;
}
```

Now with this I can insert a `Produto` entity with one selected `Categoria`. I am trying now solve the insertion without need to select a `Categoria`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set Categoria of your Produto by selecting from database by ID comes from client. You are just inserting Produto but Categoria. So İn your situation Categoria is not persistable and should be.

Comment: But I think I do this (the options from select are appended using jquery/json, and the value is the ID of Categoria, like this `target.append('<option class="form-control" value="'+item.id+'">'+item.nome+'</option>')`). Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use **merge** instead of **persist**.  persist can only insert a new record whereas merge will perform an insert or update.  Your error occurs because, when they select an existing id, you actually want to do an update, not an insert. Be sure to use the result returned from merge as the new value of your entity after you call it.

Comment: Ok, when I use merge instead of persist, I got no error, selecting or not an option; but when I select an option, it isn't stored in the database.

Comment: @KleberMota Try entitManager.flush() after your entityManager.merge()  and make sure you are closing the transaction afterwards. Also make sure you are doing something like myEntity = entityManager.merge(myEntity)

Comment: Ok, I notice now what's really happening is that: the transaction is updating Categoria with empty values. After insert a new Produto with one Categoria select, for instance, I need go back to re-insert the values from the selected Categoria.